# How to add const fs = require('fs') to Electron, in renderer without including nodeIntegration: true, contextIsolation: false

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I need to build an IPC, but I do not understand how to do this. I read the documentation and this is -https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738, but couldn't do anything, how the code should look like in my case, so that this earned? All tutorial videos have nodeIntegration: true, contextIsolation: false, but this could be a security risk

```
main.js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url');

const electron = require('electron')

// Enable live reload for all the files inside your project directory
require('electron-reload')(__dirname);

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

```
renderer.js


const fs = require('fs');
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 65:
      fs.appendFile('message.txt', 'data to append', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
       
      });
        console.log('file added');
     
    break;
      default:
          console.log("Key not found!");
  }
};
```

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
    <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly expose Node.js internals in Electron's renderer code.

Instead, you set up an IPC handler using `ipcMain.handle` in your main process code that does whatever you want in Node.js, optionally accepting parameters and returning the result of your operation.

You then expose a function in your window's preload script, which calls this IPC handler using `ipcRenderer.invoke`, passing any arguments along.

In your renderer, you then call the exposed function thus offloading the I/O work to your main process, where this kind of stuff should be done in the first place.

A simple example using `fs.promises.readFile`. You should be able to adapt this to your use case easily:

`main.js`

```js
const { ipcMain } = require("electron");
const fs = require("fs/promises");

ipcMain.handle("readFile", (event, filePath) => {
  return fs.readFile(filePath);
});
```

`preload.js`

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("myFS", {
  readFile: (filePath) => {
    return ipcRenderer.invoke("readFile", filePath);
  },
});
```

`renderer.js`

```
async function someRendererFunction() {
  const fileContents = await window.myFS.readFile("/some/file/path");

  console.log("read", fileContents);

  return fileContents;
}
```

Generally, when developing with Electron, you should try not to do everything in your renderer and instead have your main process do as much work as possible. The renderer should request the main process to do that work when needed. This way, it can completely focus all its resources on UI work without worrying about running expensive or blocking operations.

By design, JavaScript is single-threaded, but Electron offers the unique advantage of running multiple processes simultaneously, so when you're doing work in your renderers only, the main process will only sit there idling and waiting for something to do.